# Help understanding mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, configuration

Let's say I have the following filesystem setup on my webserver:

```
/www/web/foo/widget.php
...
/www/app/mvc/controllers/WidgetController.php
```

I need to figure out how to use mod_rewrite to map page requests (and their respective GET/POST data) for widget.php to its controller WidgetController.php.

It looks like mod_rewrite is *super-powerful* and thus complex. Is there a quick and easy way for someone to explain to me how to accomplish this?  What files do I have to change? Can someone show me a sample rule for this "widget" example?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nothing is quick and easy.

## Setup

First you must make sure that you have the package installed

To use mod_rewrite, you need to load the extension. Usually, this is done by inmporting the rewrite.so module in the apache2 global configuration (`/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`)

Usually all mod_rewrite instruction are written in the virtual host definition. (Say: `/etc/apache2/site-available/000default`)

## Usage

### First step

To enable rewrite for one site, you have to ask for it with :

```
RewriteEngine On
```

Then you can begin to write rules. The basic you need to write rules is describe by the following diagram :

[image: Rewrite States]

(See also : [How does url rewrite works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6430858/how-does-url-rewrite-works/6438176#6438176))

To help me understand how it works, always consider it from the server side (not client side). 
You receive an URL from the client. This URL has a certain format that you had defined. (E.g. `http://blog.com/article/myarticle-about-a-certain-topic`). But apache can't understand this by himself, so we need to help him. We know that the controller is `page.php` and can look up article by name.

### Getting information

So now we forge a `regex` to extract information from the URL. All regex are matched against what is following your domain name (here : `article/myarticle-about-a-certain-topic` without the first `/` -- It can be written though on recent version of rewrite)

Here we need the article's name: `^article/(.*)$` will do the job of matching URL against `article/<something>` and capturing `<something>` into `$1`. (For characters meaning, I advise you to look a tutorial on regex. Here ^ is beginning of the string, invisible position after the `.com/`, and $ the end of the URL)

So now we need to informe apache that this URL means `http://myblog.com/page.php?article=myarticle-about-a-certain-topic`

This is achieved by using a `RewriteRule`

```
RewriteRule ^article/(.*)$ page.php?article=$1
```

### Restricting to conditions

To go a bit on advance topics, you may want to apply this rule only if the article name is fetch by GET method. To do this, you can include a `RewriteCond` like

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} GET
```

It goes BEFORE a `RewriteRule` in the file but is tested AFTER it.

#### Flags

If you are making lot of redirection/rewrite, you will have to understand [flags](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteflags)

The most used are `[L]` and `[R]`. A little explanation on those :

- `[R]` ask for redirection, it can be tuned like `[R=302]` where 302 is a redirection status number of the HTTP protocol. This will force the client to make a new request with the rewritten URL. Therefore he will see the rewritten URL in his address bar.
- `[L]` forces apache to stop treating rules. Be advise that it does mean that the current incoming URL will stop being modified, but the rewritten URL *WILL* go again through the process of rewriting. Keep this in mind if you want to avoid loops.

## Conclusion

So you end up with the following block of instructions

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} GET
RewriteRule ^article/(.*)$ page.php?article=$1
```

## See also

You can find additional resources here :

- A basic tester http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/
- Cheat sheet : http://www.ranzs.com/?p=43
- Query_String examples : http://statichtml.com/2010/mod-rewrite-baseon-on-query-string.html
- Tips : http://www.noupe.com/php/10-mod_rewrite-rules-you-should-know.html and http://www.ranzs.com/?p=35