# Rewrite rules to hide an url

Tags: security, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i need to hide full path and show shortly:

`www.site.com/this/is/path/to/hide/page.php`  -->  `www.site.com`

Any idea to do it with **.htaccess** *apache* and **rewrite rules**??

**EXAMPLE**:
If i type `www.site.com` i want open `index.php` (in /),
but if i go to `/hidden/path` i want to open `file.php` (in hidden/path)
**mantaining browser url in www.site.com**.

---

**EDIT**:
i want to see in the browser bar `www.site.com` and i want to open page at `/this/is/path/to/hide/page.php` .

thanks

Comment: How should that resource be located/identified if not using the URL/URI?

Comment: No. **Can you serve me what I want if I call your name?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I explained in : [How does url rewrite works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6430858/how-does-url-rewrite-works/6438176#6438176) every rewrite triggers a new call to the rewritten URL. (HTTP 3xx code).

So the client will ask for `www.site.com/this/is/path/to/hide/page.php`, would be redirected to `www.site.com` and will be served the index page as a normal user.

There is no way to tell the client to display one URL in the browser bar instead of another, client browser will always make a new request. (Or you could impersonate any site for example)

If you are not against the use of a cookie, or can use environment variable you may be able to do something like :

```
RewriteRule this/is/path/to/hide/page.php / [co:knowHiddenPath=true]
```

The environment variable as same syntax with `E` instead of `co`.

(See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html for cookie information)

Your index page should then check this cookie/variable to serve the hidden page or not.

Another solution would be to enable access with password to your file. So even if someone know the URL he would not access the file. Security by obscurity is does not exists.

Answer (score 0):

You can I believe do that with an [Alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html),

```
Alias / /this/is/path/to/hide/page.php
```

This directive needs to be in your `<VirtualHost>`

Comment: Now the only thing that you would show is the the file: `page.php`. **Yes path will be still be hidden.**

Comment: VirtualHost is not in htaccess, true? What kind of file that i need to do? Where?

Answer (score 0):

This will use **mod_rewrite** and you can put this into your **.htaccess**

```
# Activate Rewrite Engine
RewriteEngine On

# Home page rewrite rule
RewriteRule ^$ /this/is/path/to/hide/page.php [QSA,L]
```

This will ONLY work if you hit website root (e.g. `http://www.example.com/`)

Comment: @LazyOne Ok, but i need to do exactly the opposite! I go to /hidden/path.php and i want see www.mysite.com. thanks.

Comment: @Paska What do you mean by "see"? You want to be **redirected** to the root -- e.g. you type that path in the browser and it redirects you to the root and you see just `www.mysite.com` in the browser bar? Or you want that URL stays the same in address bar (as you typed) but it will show you (in the browser) the home page?

Comment: Sorry, i want to see in the browser bar www.site.com and i want to open page at /hidden/path.php.

Comment: @Paska So you type `www.site.com` but want to see the `www.site.com/hidden/path.php` instead and browser should keep URL as is. Is that correct?

Comment: No, if i type **www.site.com** i want see **index.php (in /)**, but if i go to **/hidden/path** i want to see **file.php (in hidden/path)** **mantaining browser url in www.site.com**.

Comment: @Paska That does not work just like that. It has to be something else involved. You cannot do what you want by just doing URL rewriting. No. Maybe you can show some real example (from real site) so I can look and understand better what you want to achieve and maybe explain you how they did it?