# avoiding duplicate urls wih my mod_write

Tags: mod-rewrite, seo

At the moment, I have a simple .htaccess that tidies up my page urls, by knocking the .php off the end, or adding it, depending on which way you look at it.

Basically, /about.php will become /about.

However, this results in my page being accessible on both of those urls. I can just suck it up and use rel=canonical tags but I'd also like to tidy it in my htaccess.

Is there a better way (clever rule) to 301 the .php to the none .php version, other than manually specifying each url?

Also, do I really need those rewritecond rules?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>


RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1.php [QSA,L]


ErrorDocument 404 /404


</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

To redirect (301) each .php-URL to the non-.php version (in case it's an existing file) you could use this one:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.php\ HTTP/.\..$
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ /$1 [QSA,R=301,L]
```

The first two RewriteCond in your .haccess are not really required, because you will have some conflicts anyway, e.g. if you have a file `foo.htm` and `foo.htm.php`, which one should be shown when `foo.htm` is requested?

So the complete `mod_rewrite` block:

```
RewriteEngine On
# redirect /foo.php to /foo
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
 RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.php\ HTTP/.\..$
 RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ /$1 [QSA,R=301,L]
# rewrite /foo to /foo.php
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: See my answer. I'll also improve my other post on URL rewriting how-to. It does only states this implicitly.

Answer (score 0):

In you original rules, you are just saying that any page that is not a file or a directory has to be redirected to the same name with `.php` appended.

So what you need to do to "remove" access to the `.php` file is to mask it with a redirection.
So you will tell the client browser that `foo/foo.php` is in fact `foo/foo`.

This will trigger a new request to `foo/foo` by the client.

Then you tell the server that `foo/foo` is in fact `foo/foo.php`. This will trigger an internal request to `foo/foo.php`. So here you have a loop. We need to avoid that. The best workaround I've found is to check wethere the `%{REDIRECT_URL}` is empty or not.

Finally rules are :

```
# External redirection from real file to virtual with safe guard for internal redirection.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REDIRECT_URL} !^$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ /$1 [QSA,R=301,L]

# Internal redirection to real file.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1.php [QSA,L]
```

Do not forget that ANY rewrite/redirection triggers a new request!

See : [How does url rewrite works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6430858/how-does-url-rewrite-works/6438176#6438176)

Comment: hmmm. Annoying. Working for me... Need to lurk moar on this issue.

Comment: Well the try to add `E=REDIRECT_URL:$1` to the last RewriteRule flags?

Comment: I found a solution: check `%{THE_REQUEST}` for `.php`. (`%{REQUEST_URI}` doesn't work too..)

Comment: In fact, why would people ask for `.php` files? If all the links on the page are without suffixe, then they'll never be called. By the way, what would be the problem if someone once call a `.php` file anyway.