# Is it possible to extract var from dummy url, use it in meta, but display original dummy url?

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Let's say I have the following url: example.com/123456

That url doesn't point to anything - the 123456 is a variable.
With PHP and/or htaccess I wonder if I can:

1. get the "123456" var
2. push the var into a meta tag in
   example.com/index.php
3. show the original url in the address bar,
   but display content redirected from example.com/index.php (123456 is
   ignored, it's just a dummy url).

I'm able to do 1 & 2 with an htaccess rewrite.  I have a feeling I can do #3 via javascript, but I wonder if there's a cleaner solution that won't make the address bar change more than needed.  Also, I don't want to be hacky - I wonder if this is a legit process?

Here's what I've got so far with .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9\+/=]+)$ ?t=$1 [NC,R=301,L]
```

And for the index.php I'm just using:

```
<meta name="foo" content="https://example.com/<?php echo $_GET['t'] ?>" />
```

All this works, but in order to get the meta var in php, the url gets changed to example.com/?t=123456.  I want to display the dummy url: example.com/123456 but show content from example.com/index.php

The difference between my question and the possible duplicate is that I already am using rewrite.  See also the answer to my question, which is nowhere mentioned in the possible duplicate.

Comment: First show us the code you have tried and we can probably help you fix it.

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does url rewrite works?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6430858/how-does-url-rewrite-works)

Comment: @TinyGiant the solution to my problem was to use [PT] (instead of [R=301]), as shown in that first section of the link you mentioned.  If you want to add an official answer, I'll accept it, else I can write a recap answer to my own question.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What solved my problem was to use the [PT] flag instead of the [R=301] flag.  [PT] means "passthrough" and allows you to display a new url without changing the address.  The new .htaccess code I'm using:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9\+/=]+)$ ?id=$1 [NC,PT,L]
```

Thanks to Tiny Giant for the helpful link and pointing me in the right direction:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html