# How to replace browser URL with Indy's TIdHTTPServer component?

Tags: delphi, indy

I've got an Indy HTTP server using the `TIdHTTPServer` component.  I'm wanting the browser URL to be rewritten like Apache and IIS do using URL Rewrite modules.

For example: If someone goes to `https://www.mydomain2.com` I want the URL in the browser to show `https://www.mydomain1.com`.

I'm pretty sure using Javascript's `history.pushState` is not the answer.

I have tried using Javascript's `history.pushState('data to be passed', 'Title of the page', '/www.mydomain1.com');` as an alternative.  However, when I go to `https://www.mydomain2.com` it appends to the current URL like `https://www.mydomain2.com/www.domain1.com`.

My understanding is `history.pushState` doesn't allow for a full URL replacement due to security issues.

My server headers being (and I'm just shooting in the dark):

```
aResponseInfo.CustomHeaders.AddValue('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');
aResponseInfo.CustomHeaders.AddValue('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','*');
aResponseInfo.CustomHeaders.AddValue('Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
  'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization');
aResponseInfo.CustomHeaders.AddValue('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
```

I'm having trouble finding a solution.

Answer (score 4):

The only way to do this from the *server* side is to instruct the client to request a new URL. You can use the `TIdHTTPResponseInfo.Redirect()` method for that purpose, eg:

```
if ARequestInfo.Host = 'www.mydomain2.com' then
  AResponseInfo.Redirect('https://www.mydomain1.com');
```

But, note that the client will no longer BE AT `https://www.mydomain2.com` anymore, it will navigate itself to `https://www.mydomain1.com` instead.

If you want the client to STAY AT `https://www.mydomain2.com` but DISPLAY `https://www.mydomain1.com`, that can only be done via client side scripting that manipulates the browser's address bar.

Comment: My understanding is that there is not a way of doing client side scripting due to security reasons?  Would you know where to point me to find out how this can be done?

Comment: See [How to modify the URL without reloading the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/)

Comment: Remy, while I try to figure out a solution there seems to be valid reason for wanting to do URL Rewrites.  is there a chance this might be available in a future Indy build?

Comment: See [How does url rewrite works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6430858/). "Redirect" is already implemented in Indy. "Rewrite" is not, but there is nothing stopping you from implementing "Rewrite" yourself in your `OnCommand...` handlers today, it is just a matter of how you decide to interpret the requested URLs. And no, there are no plans to have Indy implement "Rewrite" for you anytime soon.